# Distance between point and line and between line and plane

Tags: linear-algebra

recently I stumbled upon a problem which I personally disagree with the answer. It follows:

Determine the distance between the point $P = (1,-3,6)$ and the line $$x = 1+t\\y = -3t\\z = 2+t$$

Also, considering a complete separate situation, determine the distance between the plane $$\pi = 2x+y+z-1=0$$ and the line $$x = 3-t\\y = -2+3t\\z = -1-t$$

I was wondering if you could help me check the final answer. The answers that I've found (which are different from the book) are below

First question:
$$\frac{\sqrt{1166}}{11}$$
Second question:
$$\frac{\sqrt{6}}{3}$$

Thank you,

Best Regards,

Bruno

Comment: What are your answers?

Comment: If you don't post your answers we can't check them.  One of us could post a solution but you wont learn if we do all the work for you.

Comment: I just posted the answers John, but as I said, they differ from the textbook. Best Regards!

Answer (score 1):

the distance between the point P and the straight line is given by
$d(P,g)=\sqrt{(x-1)^2+(y+3)^2+(z-6)^2}$ polugging $x=3-t,y=-2+3t,z=-1-t$ in the equation we obtain 
$d(P,g)=\sqrt{(3-t-1)^2+(-2+3t+3)^2+(6+1+t)^2}$
now you can differentiate with respect to $t$
using the vectors then we can us a formula
this can you see here
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-LineDistance3-Dimensional.html
and here
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-PlaneDistance.html

Comment: Thank you Dr. Sonnhard, that would surely give a correct result, but I was wondering if working with vectors would provide a simpler answer. Best Regards!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is certainly possible to solve your problem using vectors.

The shortest distance between the point $P$ and the line $L$ lies on a plane than goes through $P$ and is perpendicular to the line. Now the line points in the direction $(-1, 3, -1)$. We need to find two vectors perpendicular to it, in order to construct our plane. It is easy to see that the vectors $(3, 1, 0)$ and $(0, 1, 3)$ satisfy this requirement. The equation for the plane is now given by:

Plane: $(1, -3, 6) + r (3, 1, 0) + s (0, 1, 3)$

Line: $(1, 0, 2) + t (-1, 3, 1)$

The intersection is found be setting these formulas equal to each other. This gives you three equations (for $x, y $ and $z$) with three parameters ($r, s$ and $t$). The solution yields the coordinates of the intersection. From this the distance to $P$ is easily computed.